# Ending and restarting a program from user input

Tags: java

I am having a few issues,

1. I am having issues getting my program to actually end.
2. I can't figure out when I prompt the user to play again how to initiate a new game.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
import java.util.*;

public class HiLowGuessingGame {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Creates a random number generator
    Random random= new Random();
    // For getting input from the user
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number = random.nextInt(100);
    int guess = +1;

    //Counts the number of guesses
    int guesscount = 0;
    guesscount ++;

    //Allows user to quit the game
    String input;
    int quit = 0;

    String playagain;
        String y="y";
        String n="n";



    // Prompts user for their next guess
    System.out.println("Enter a guess from 1 to 100, Enter 0 to quit");         


    // Loop until the user guesses correctly
    while (true){ 
    // Reads the next guess
        guess = sc.nextInt();
    //If guess it to low or high
        if (guess == quit){
        System.out.println("Game Over!");}
        else if (guess < number ){
        System.out.println("Guess is too low, please try again");
        guesscount ++; }
        else if(guess > number ){
        System.out.println("Guess is too high, please try again");
        guesscount ++; }

        // Correct guess and number of guesses
        else {
        System.out.println("Your guess is correct = " + number + "\n" +"Number of Guesses = " +guesscount );

        while (true) {
             // Play again?
            boolean isplayagain = true;
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("play another game?(y/n)");
                String playagainResponse = sc.next();
                if (playagainResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter a guess from 1 to 100, Enter 0 to quit");
                    guess = sc.nextInt();
                    break;
                } else if (playagainResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                    isplayagain = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isplayagain) {
                break;
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, and I noticed that you use break statements to exit out of the for loops, but you never break out of the outermost for loop, so the game never actually ends.

In this case however, I would recommend not using break and use System.exit(0), which will end the game normally. I'll add a reference link at the bottom. This should fix your issue of the game not ending.

As for your other problem, I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that it doesn't restart a new game properly? The random number is only issued at the start of the program, so when a new game is started, the random number stays the same. Also, the guess count isn't reset with a new game. I would just put all the code which resets the variables in the if-statement responsible for starting a new game.

Good luck!

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)

Answer (score 0):

I changed your program a bit to do what you want.
If i get what you are trying to do i think this is the code for this.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HiLowGuessingGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Creates a random number generator
    Random random= new Random();
    // For getting input from the user
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number = random.nextInt(100);
    int guess = +1;

    //Counts the number of guesses
    int guesscount = 0;
    guesscount ++;

    //Allows user to quit the game
    String input;
    int quit = 0;

    String playagain;
        String y="y";
        String n="n";

        boolean isplayagain = false;

    // Prompts user for their next guess
    System.out.println("Enter a guess from 1 to 100, Enter 0 to quit");         


    // Loop until the user guesses correctly
    while (true){ 
    // Reads the next guess
        guess = sc.nextInt();
    //If guess it to low or high
        if (guess == quit){
        System.out.println("Game Over!");
        break;}

        else if (guess < number ){
        System.out.println("Guess is too low, please try again");
        guesscount ++; }
        else if(guess > number ){
        System.out.println("Guess is too high, please try again");
        guesscount ++; }

        // Correct guess and number of guesses
        else {
        System.out.println("Your guess is correct = " + number + "\n" +"Number of Guesses = " +guesscount );

       // while (true) {
             // Play again?

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("play another game?(y/n)");
                String playagainResponse = sc.next();
                if (playagainResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                    System.out.println("New game starts now!");                   
                    isplayagain=true;
                    break;
                } else if (playagainResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                    isplayagain = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isplayagain)break;//cause of the program to not end if user gives n
        }
        if(isplayagain){
            number = random.nextInt(100);
            guesscount=0;                       
            System.out.println("Enter a guess from 1 to 100, Enter 0 to quit");
            isplayagain=false;}

        }
    }
}
```